# undefined method ` ' for #<ContactsController:0x007fc3a821e300>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following the tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html ) to create my own web app for create a contact manager.

When I want to create a new contact, I have code in my contacts_controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.save
    redirect_to @contact
  end

  private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :phonenumber, :notes)
    end
end
```

In the view I have

```
<h1>New Contact</h1>
<%= form_for :contact, url: contacts_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :firstname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :phonenumber %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phonenumber %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :notes %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :notes %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'welcome/index'
      root 'welcome#index'
      resources :contacts
    end

However, when I submit the form, I got this error message.
[image: error]

I think I followed the tutorial correctly and have the new method in my class. This seems weird to me and I have no idea to start debugging this app.

Comment: Can you show the full error? Don't just past the message. It's hard to tell without a proper stack trace. Please paste that and all the relevant code. Your form seems wrong. Form_for :contact should probably be form_for @contact.

Comment: I have included all relevant code now. Let me know if any other information needed. Thx!

Comment: Have you copied this method from somewhere? If so, there might be some extra characters at the end of the line (most likely `\r`) which are not displayed on the screen but are interpreted by ruby parses as regular characters.

Comment: It is. I checked that there are some spaces after the method name